# Django Rest Framework Serialization error in ListAPIView

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-generic-views

I am getting below error

**Error** -- 'many' is an invalid keyword argument for this function"

In ListAPIView while serializing a object.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'uuid', 'email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'mobile_no', 'dob', 'username',)


class CorporateProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     user = UserSerializer(many=True)

     class Meta:
        model = CorporateProfile
        fields = ('user', 'id', 'uuid', 'company_name', 'company_type',)
```

views.py

```
class CorporateListView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = CorporateProfile
    queryset = CorporateProfile.objects.all()
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

There was my mistake in views. I wrote model in serializer class instead of serializer class.

```
serializer_class = CorporateProfileSerializer
```